# Gradle and Android: how to use the latest available build tools?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How to let Gradle (more specifically, Gradle Android plugin) use the last installed version of Build Tools?

Answer (score 1):

Goto **File** > **Project Structure**

Under **Module** > select your project

Under **Properties** > You just change stuff there

You'll need all the latest sdks downloaded from the sdk manager before hand!

Comment: Is there a way to do it without Android Studio, only with `gradle` command and build script?

Answer (score 1):

When you add version number and Gradle Sycn

```
android {
...
buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
...
}
```

Gradle will auto download (if it is not downloaded previously) the specified version from the repository.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html